# what should be the Hikari maxLifetime for mysql wait_time out value 28800

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application with below HikariCP properties enabled in application.properties and in mysql i have wait_timeout = 28800

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=9
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=28799990
```

I still get the below error

> 13:02:46.103 [http-nio-8082-exec-2] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@13f6e098 (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

what values i need to set in HikariCP to fix this issue

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

```
  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  
  public Map<String, Object> getSlideData(String date, String sp){
      SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(sp)
              .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
              .useInParameterNames(ReportGeneratorConstants.TIMEPERIOD)
              .declareParameters(
                      new SqlParameter(ReportGeneratorConstants.TIMEPERIOD,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)
              );
      Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
      map.put(ReportGeneratorConstants.TIMEPERIOD, date);
      
      return simpleJdbcCall.execute(map);
      
  }
}
```

I am using simpleJdbcCall to call the stored procedure, I know that simpleJdbcCall uses multithread to run the stored procedure, What i want to know is, does simpleJdbcCall releases/close all connection to pool once execute() is completed (does spring boot take care of closing connections) if yes, where i can see the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why connections can be terminated. Usually there's something in the  middle, tipically a firewall, that drops connections after set amount of time. Find what time that is and set the max life to at least 1 minutes before that. Hikari has a background thread that expires connections but I think it triggers every few seconds; I'm mentioning this as it's not exact to the millisecond.

A note that Hikari will try to keep the minimumIdle number of connections, so usually new connections will be open in the background and won't create a pause in the application to wait for a new connection.

## Edit

I'm not familiar with Azure, so I'm not sure if the network stack drops connections after a certain amount of time. Personally, I never set the idle timeout nor max-life settings as long as the ones you have as the chances of a connection dropping is quite high in a cloud environment (in my experience). As an example, in AWS, our data team suggests to use a max lifetime of 5 minutes and idletimeout of 1 minute and this is in a platform with high traffic.

Opening a DB connection is quite fast and usually happens behind the scenes. My suggestion would be to use these settings, but you have to validate them that they work ok for the load of your application (based on the ones you added on the comment below):

```
# set this equal to maximum pool size if the traffic has burst
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=30
# It's the same as the default = 30 minutes
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000   
# It's the same as the default = 10 minutes
spring.datasource.hikari.keepalive-time=60000
```

Comment: Thanks @Augusto, we are using httpd with below virtual host. Does this also affect the connection termination ? 

`<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on

  ServerName example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /    http://localhost:8082/
  ProxyPassReverse /    http://localhost:8082/
  ProxyPass       /  ajp://localhost:8082/
  ProxyPassReverse    /  ajp://localhost:8082/
 
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: This shouldn't affect the DB connection as it looks like it's apache forwarding http connections to the servlet container (probably Tomcat?). The DB connections definitely won't go through this as Apache doesn't support Layer 4 proxing (as far as I know!)

Comment: Thanks for the help. We dont have any firewall running between mysql server (Azure , centos 8) and app server (Azure, centOS 8) . And I have below configuration added in application.properties
`spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=29
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
#spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=120000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=0
spring.datasource.hikari.keepalive-time=10000
`
I get same exception as in the intial question

Comment: Thanks @Augusto, The Hikari configurations for some reason are not working. Checked with different values and combinations. I have added the piece of code which i am using to call the stored procedure. Do you see any issues with code or you think we need to close connections manually ? in case of success / exception